# Enable to start other activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have home and exit button in main Activity , when I click Exit button the application is closed. But when I click home button it is getting RunTimeException.

This is the MainActivity's `onCreate` method code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
    exit_app = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_app);

    home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });

    exit_app.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

This is FirstActivity's `onCreate` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstactivitylayout);

            home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            exit_app = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_app);


            home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            exit_app.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();

                }
            });


    }
```

Comment: Have you added the new activity in the AndroidManifest? please post the LogCat and the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
atcom.android.bioasiasample.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:24)
atandroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

Comment: see line no 24 of FirstActivity.java something is null and add logcat in question

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi yes i have added new activity in manifest file

Comment: @Anwesh Did you use any jar  / library files inside in your project?

Comment: can you post some relevent code of FirstActivity.class.

Comment: @Kamal i have posted both the activity codes plz check it

Comment: @Anwesh You should mention the code setcontentview(...) on main activity also.

Comment: @Venkatesh  i have removed in this comment box because of specific characters got it

Comment: Yes in Main Activity you haven't used setContentView or you have forgotten to paste it here. If you have provided the contentView, please check for same Id for home Button in both Activities.

Comment: @Anwesh could you post your remaining logcat if that has been seen by you?

Comment: @Kamal   i have used content view while i am posting here two lines are deleted , let me post again oh god

Comment: In both Activities you have provided same Id for home Button. I am not sure but please check.

Comment: Kamal comments might be correct one. Becoz we can't mention same id for our components. AVD  will confusion on take the correct components from your layout.

Comment: @Kamal@Venkatesh  I have changed the IDs even though same result

Comment: @Anwesh could you please clean your project by choose menu project->project clean->ur project  and run your project now? tell me if the problems is still come. Becoz you may be change the layout config , but it is not change/affect on your workspace.

Comment: @Anwesh Ok. Could you please send your manifest xml and remaing logcat error pointing if you have seen  some more?

Comment: @Anwesh can you post the remaining part of logcat, so that we can guess which component is getting nullpointer.

Comment: Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.bioasiasample/com.android.bioasiasample.FirstActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

Comment: atandroid.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
atdalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
atcom.android.bioasiasample.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:22)
atandroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)     These are the logcat